# How to fix power BI flow map always count my lat and lon?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a flow map on Power BI.
I have my coordinates and I changed the data to Longitude and Latitude.
But when I drag my coordinates to the box, it always counts it. How could I fix this?
**Data_table** [image: Data_table]
Thanks

I tried to change the data to dimension as suggested instead of numeric.
But still, it shows count instead of points on the map.

Btw I have linked those two table with common key.

And I also tried to use only one table. With information of lat and lon in it. It is still counting my Lat and lon.
**Data_table**[image: tried with one table]

Comment: These fields are in another table and there is no relationship between them, so Power BI can't know the related coordinates, gets multiple values and aggregate them. You must redesign your model.

Comment: I did linked those two table tho. But I also tried to use only one table. It is still show me the count. Any good insights? Thanks